# Specific sequence in $l^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I have a problem. I am trying to find sequence $x\in l^2$, witch satisfies:

$(\forall p<2) (x\not\in l^p)$.

Is it possible? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the sequence $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}\ln(n+2)}$?

Comment: You  are welcome.